# Truncated Inccorrect date value while calling nested function

Tags: mysql

I have two function.

1. fn_validate_date
2. fn_validation

fn_validate_date code:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_validate_date`(
    `dt_date` DATE

 )
 RETURNS date
 LANGUAGE SQL
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
 CONTAINS SQL
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 COMMENT 'Returns the associated value of given attribute for given employee                for a particular date.'
 BEGIN
    SET dt_date = IF(dt_date IS NULL OR dt_date ='', CURRENT_DATE, dt_date);
    RETURN dt_date;
 END
```

fn_validation code:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_validation`(
    `dt_date` DATE
 )
 RETURNS date
 LANGUAGE SQL
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
 CONTAINS SQL
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 COMMENT ''
 BEGIN
    RETURN fn_validate_date(dt_date);
 END
```

Now when I am calling fn_validate_date as below

```
 SELECT `fn_validate_date`(null);
```

It's working well but when I calling fn_validation it's giving me an error.

```
SELECT `fn_validation`(null);
```

[image]

My question is why I didn't get error while calling fn_validate_date?

Answer (score 0):

In fn_validate_date, the dt_date-parameter is type of date and you are comparing it to a string datatype. No need for that. Date datatype cannot contain ''. It either is NULL or has a date value in it.

So instead of:

```
SET dt_date = IF(dt_date IS NULL OR dt_date ='', CURRENT_DATE, dt_date);
```

You can simply use:

```
return ifnull( dt_date, current_date() );
```

Comment: But while calling fn_validate_date it's not giving me an error. It's giving error while calling fn_validation in which I calling fn_validate_date.

Comment: MySQL does not short circuit the if-clause when function is called from another function. Just fix the code and you will be fine.

Comment: With closer look it looks more like the difference how/when MySQL converts strings to date rather than the short circuiting issue. Anyways, you should not compare dates to an empty string.

Comment: I know I can't compare a date with an empty string and also it's working well if I remove it. But while calling fn_validate_date, why am I not getting the same error. Is it a runtime error?

Comment: MySQL seems to treat the string to date conversion differently when you call a function directly compared to situation when a function calls a function. No apparent reason for this. One of those things where you fix your error and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I disable strict mode and it's working well.

```
 SET sql_mode =''
```

To disable strict mode in MySQL. I am not sure why MySql short-circuited IF condition as I am passing NULL in the input parameter of fn_validation.